# resulting sum in binary 16

Tags: binary

I have answered the question  but i could not understand the part where its says get the resulting sum in 16-bit binary, check your answer by converting the sum into decimal.

1.Add ‘A’ and ‘B’ in binary to get the resulting sum in 16-bit binary, check your answer by converting the sum into decimal.

`Decimal number = 58927634
A= 5892   to Binary  1011 1000 0010 0
B= 7634 to Binary  1110 1110 1001 0
 a + b = 11010011010110`

thanks alot

Regards

Comment: It means, use 16 bits to represent the sum of A and B.

Comment: Twelve plus thirteen, in four digit decimal, is 0025.

Comment: and how can i do that please give me an example, what about my answer is it right thanks m8

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain:

```
A = 00005892 
B = 00007634
```

in *base 10* number system, with 8 **decimals** to represent it.

and...

```
A = 0001 0111 0000 0100
B = 0001 1101 1101 0010
```

in *base 2* number system, with 16 **bits** to represent it.

I hope it makes sense to you now.

And the sum of A and B, in base 2 number system with 16 bits to represent it....

```
0011 0100 1101 0110
```

although, we needed just 14 bits....

Your answer is correct, but its width is 14 bits long.